# Must match all words in MATCH AGAINST mysql

Tags: mysql, match-against

```
SELECT *,
MATCH (`text`) AGAINST ('my work involves for' IN BOOLEAN MODE) `score`
FROM `messages` WHERE MATCH (`must_match`) AGAINST ('my work involves for' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY `score` DESC
```

So here user input is 'my work involves for'

```
id   text                 must_match
---  ----                 ------
1    my work is to help   work,help
2    work involves help   involves,work
```

Now I want result if mus_match column's all words match in user input
So, from above row our result will be 2nd row

must_match column will contain words from text column

Comment: Does `must_match` always have 2 comma separated values?

Comment: No, that can be more than 2

Answer (score 0):

After spent a lot of time, I am unable to come up with a solution/workaround for your task. The main reason behind this is that you have **Multi-valued Attribute** in your table: `must_match`. It contains comma-separated values and number of values are also not predefined.

First of all, I will request you to go through [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3653574/2225030) in order to realize the cons of storing a delimited list in a column.

```
id        text1         must_match
1   my work is to help  work
1   my work is to help  help
2   work involves help  involves
2   work involves help  work
```

Now, if you are able to convert your table in 1NF and store multiple values of `must_match` in multiple rows (as described above) then keep reading for solution and if not, please comment the reason behind that.

**Solution:**

```
select id,text1,
MATCH (text1) AGAINST ('my work involves for' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as score
from t t1
where locate(must_match,"my work involves for") > 0
group by id
having count(*) = (select count(*) from t where id = t1.id);
```

**Note:** If `id` is a **Primary key**,then you can `group by` using `text` column too.

[Click here for Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f3be65/2/0)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Is it an affordable approach for you?